# Home page on condition basis in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have set category page my default home page.But now i want to show CMS`(Home page)` for not logged in user while for logged-in i want to show category page.Means how i can set logic that can load both cms pages. How can i do that ? Thanks for any help in advance

```
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
load->category page
 <?php else: ?>//If user is NOT logged in
    Load home page default one

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hello,Adda ,are you already add  category page for home???

Comment: What if non-logged in user click on category url ?

Comment: yes i have set it is default page.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy i hide category from links

Comment: IF you always redirect user to category page if logged in, then how can he perform other actions like adding product to cart ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy i want to put only condition on home link.Means when user want to see home page it will check condition and redirect user on that basis.i didn't show category or products to unregistered users.that part is done only redirection needed.

Comment: I did not get your complete flow for redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want only to check condition on home page .You can do like this .Change little bit code for CMS controller like this :

```
class Mage_Cms_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
       if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('catalog/category/view/id/3'));

}else{
        $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_HOME_PAGE);
        if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
            $this->_forward('defaultIndex');
        }
    }
    }
```

Try and inform me about results.Hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This might work in your case :

// condition depending on login status of user

```
if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
{
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
die();
}
else
{
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('YOUR_CATEGORY_URL'));
die();
}

IF above doesn't work, try this :

$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('YOUR_CATEGORY_URL'));
} else {
   Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
}
```

Comment: keep a die(); function at the end. See my edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: If you use controller_action_predispatch event, the above code will result in infinite loop even if you put DIE();

Comment: Okay then try my below code the one which plays with session.

Comment: Its one and the same thing